# Qual a diferença entre Math.random() e java.util.Random?

Tags: java, random

Qual a diferença em utilizar o `random` sem o `import`, direto no método.

```
public class random {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int x = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
        System.out.println(x); 

    }

}
```

Ou com o import na classe, qual é a diferença?

```
import java.util.Random;

public class random {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Random aleatorio = new Random();
        int numero = aleatorio.nextInt(10);
        System.out.println(numero);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A primeira diferença é que [Math.random()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random%28%29) é um método estático da classe [Math](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html), enquanto [java.util.Random](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) é uma classe.

Neste aspecto a vantagem de **Math.random** sobre **java.util.Random** é que não é necessário criar um objecto.

**Math.random()** retorna um *double* de 0,0 até, mas não incluindo 1.0.  Para conseguir outra gama de valores é necessário recorrer a operações como a multiplicação.
É necessário recorrer ao *cast* para convertê-lo para um número inteiro.
Internamente usa **java.util.Random** como gerador dos números.

A classe **java.util.Random** fornece formas mais flexíveis para gerar números aleatórios distribuídos uniformemente, proporcionando fácil geração de outros tipos além do *double*.

Um aspecto que pode ser interessante(em caso de testes) é que se duas instâncias de **java.util.Random** forem criados com a mesma semente(*seed*), e a mesma sequência de chamadas de métodos for feita para cada uma, elas vão gerar e retornar sequências idênticas de números.

Answer (score 4):

A classe é mais completa e flexível, permite determinar o tipo de dado que se deseja e é mais eficiente. Ela pode, por exemplo, repetir os mesmos números se usada com a mesma semente.

O método estático contido em `Math` é mais simples e resolve sem muitas preocupações, o método cuida de vários detalhes para você, consequentemente você não pode configurar como quer usar. Só trabalha com valores `double`. Ele é prático quando precisa do básico.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).